# Better to play more tickets in the same lottery, or one ticket in several lotteries?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, recreational-mathematics, lotteries

Here are some facts about a lottery:

1. The lottery happens once a week
2. Each week, a completely random number between 000 and 999 (inclusive) is picked
3. You only win if you match the number exactly

What will give me a better chance of winning at least once:

- buying one ticket for this week and one ticket for next week
- buy two tickets for the same week

It feels like buying two for the same week is better, but don't know if that is mathematically true.

I think this question is related to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2747590/better-play-100-tickets-in-one-lottery-draw-or-100-plays-draws-with-1-ticket) but the math is a little too dense for me to grasp.

Comment: Do you know how to calculate the probability that you do not win if you buy one ticket? two tickets? one ticket each week?

Comment: How do you define "*better*"?  Note the distinction that if you buy two tickets to the same lottery you can't win twice, but if you buy one ticket from each lottery you can win twice.  The total *expected value* of your winnings is the same regardless.  The point is that by playing the same lottery twice you have less chance of having won nothing and more chance of having won once and zero chance of having won twice compared to if you play two different lotteries.

Comment: @JMoravitz - ah, that is a good point. I meant it as in, a better chance of winning at least once. I will edit my post and clarify that

Comment: Does this answer your question? [If I play the lottery with a specific amount of money, should I put it all on one game or distribute it among several games](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2990504/if-i-play-the-lottery-with-a-specific-amount-of-money-should-i-put-it-all-on-on)